# How do I delete the first column in my matrix in python?

Tags: python, matrix

I have a matrix and want to delete the first column in python.  What is the best way to do that?

Ex:  Get rid of the first column of E.

```
    E E E E E
    E 1 2 3 4
    E 5 6 7 8
    E 9 1 2 3
```

The matrix is being read in from a txt file.  I am trying to use the first row as keys, get rid of the first column and use the remaining rows as values.

Here is what I have so far:

```
    matrix_filename = raw_input("Enter the scoring matrix filename:  ")  
    matrix_file = open(matrix_filename, "r")  
    matrix = matrix_file.readlines()  
    keys = matrix[0]  
    vals = matrix[1:]
```

I want the values to be the numbers only.

Thanks, guys!

Comment: is this matrix in a txt file? what sort of datatype are you reading it in as?

Comment: Just edited the above with more info.  Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

I'm going to assume that your matrix is just an array of arrays, if that is the case, the follow code works.  However, it will not delete the elements in-place, it returns a copy of the matrix with the first column removed.

```
>>> m = [ [x*5+y for y in range(5)] for x in range(5) ]
>>> m2 = [ row[1:] for row in m ]
>>> print m
[[0, 1, 2, 3, 4], [5, 6, 7, 8, 9], [10, 11, 12, 13, 14], [15, 16, 17, 18, 19], [20, 21, 22, 23, 24]]
>>> m2
[[1, 2, 3, 4], [6, 7, 8, 9], [11, 12, 13, 14], [16, 17, 18, 19], [21, 22, 23, 24]]
```

Answer (score 1):

```
vals = [line[1:] for line in matrix[1:]]
```

Just do the same thing you did to remove the first row in the matrix, but to each line individually.